# How to make the width of individual columns thicker?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

How to make the width of individual columns thicker? Otherwise there where only 1 column, it gets a little width

[example](http://jsfiddle.net/zcd3S/)

```
$(function () {
$('#container').highcharts({

    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            shadow: true
        }
    },

    series: [{
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4],
        type: 'column'
    }, {
        data: [176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4],
        type: 'column'
    }, {
        data: [176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4],
        type: 'column'
    }, {
        data: [176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4],
        type: 'column'
    }]
});
```

});

Answer (score 1):

pointWidth ([documentation](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.bar.pointWidth)) will allow you to specify the width of the individual bars.

```
plotOptions: {
        series: {
            shadow: true,
            pointWidth:5
        }
    },
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/N9frt/)

Comment: This is the total width. I need to the same schedule was different width, because he does not have enough space and it is compressed because of this, it is compressed on the whole axis. I want it shrank only where necessary.

Comment: If you are limited on width, it may be worth looking at a different type of chart.  A stacked column or line would work.

Answer (score 0):

Generally it is not possible, but you can modify SVG width element by attr() function.

```
 chart.series[0].data[4].graphic.attr({width:50});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/D6vNc/1/